# how to implement nested multi level looping in dataweave in Mule

Tags: mule

I am using `dataweave` for transforming XML to CSV. I want to know how to implement nested for loop in `dataweave`.

**Below is the input xml:**

```
 <employee>
  <id>1236</id>
  <emplinfo>
     <emplid>1961</emplid>
     <jobinfo>
        <status>T</status>
        <title>Manager</title>
        <start_date>2016-09-01</start_date>                        
     </jobinfo>
     <jobinfo>
        <status>P</status>
        <end_date>2016-08-31</end_date>
        <title>Integration Manager</title>
        <start_date>2016-08-01</start_date>
     </jobinfo>
     <jobinfo>
        <status>A</status>
        <end_date>2016-07-31</end_date>
        <title>Communications Manager</title>
        <start_date>2016-07-17</start_date>
     </jobinfo>
  </emplinfo>
  <emplinfo>
     <emplid>1801</emplid>
     <jobinfo>
        <status>T</status>
        <title>AM</title>
        <start_date>2016-09-01</start_date>                        
     </jobinfo>
  </emplinfo>
 </employee>
```

---

**Excepted output:**

```
id       empl_id status end_date   title                  start_date
1236 1961    T                 Manager                2016-09-01
1236 1961    P      2016-08-31 Integration Manager    2016-08-01
1236 1961    A      2016-07-31 Communications Manager 2016-07-17
1236 1801    T                 AM                     2016-09-01
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv
---
flatten (payload map ((parent, parentindex) -> {
    emplinfo:(parent.*emplinfo map ((emplinfo,empindex) -> {
        jobinfo:(emplinfo.*jobinfo map ((jobinfo,jobindex) -> {
            id: parent.id,
            emplid : emplinfo.emplid,
            status: jobinfo.status,
            end_date:jobinfo.end_date,
            title:jobinfo.title,
            start_date:jobinfo.start_date
        }))
    }))
}))..jobinfo
```

I have used normal csv. you can choose any kind of format. Output is

```
id,emplid,status,end_date,title,start_date
1236,1961,T,,Manager,2016-09-01
1236,1961,P,2016-08-31,Integration Manager,2016-08-01
1236,1961,A,2016-07-31,Communications Manager,2016-07-17
1236,1801,T,,AM,2016-09-01
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks your solution.

Comment: There are some changes in my input file. I am using dataweave in batch so the input is like a single records at a time and it's json format. Below is my input as json:                                                                                      {person=[{emplinfo=[{jobinfo=[{title=Support Analyst, status=A, start_date=2016-06-09}], empl_id=1961}, {jobinfo=[{title=Assistant Manager, status=A, start_date=2016-09-23}, {title=Manager, status=A, start_date=2016-07-26, end_date=2016-07-31}], empl_id=17281}], id=1394}]}

Comment: You can use the same code just change first line object payload to `payload.person`. Something like `%dw 1.0
%output application/csv
---
flatten (payload.person map ((parent, parentindex) -> {
 emplinfo:(parent.emplinfo map ((emplinfo,empindex) -> {
        jobinfo:(emplinfo.jobinfo map ((jobinfo,jobindex) -> {
            id: parent.id,
            emplid : emplinfo.empl_id,
            status: jobinfo.status,
            end_date:jobinfo.end_date,
            title:jobinfo.title,
            start_date:jobinfo.start_date
        }))
    }))
}))..jobinfo`

Comment: I tried the above mentioned code but it is throwing exception:    'Exception while executing: 
flatten (payload.person map ((parent, parentindex) -> { 
^
Type mismatch for 'flatten' operator
     found :null
  required :array. (org.mule.routing.CompositeRoutingException)]'

Comment: Thanks... It is working. Giving exception for null "payload.person'. Will add check for null.

Answer (score 0):

Do it something like this

```
Segment:(payload.segments map ((segment, segmentIndex)->
    {
        Leg:(segment.legs map ((leg, legIndex)->
            {                   
                Origin:leg.departureField.airportCodeField,
                Destination:leg.arrivalField.airportCodeField
            }))
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use map operator for looping through the members of an array. The left hand side of map is the array which is processed and right hand side will have code for how members in it should be mapped. We can use lambda functions as well.
You can name the current member and refer it as well.

```
(payload.ARRAY map ((value,index) ->
   {
       id: parent.id,
            emplid : value.emplid,
            status: value.status,

   }
)
```

Similiar depending on how you want to process the input array we can have nested map operators.

```
(payload.ARRAY map ((value,index) ->
{
(payload.ARRAY2 map ((value,index) ->
   {
       id: parent.id,
            emplid : value.emplid,
            status: value.status,

   }
)
```